# Change Softlayer snapshot property

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to change *softlayer* WEEKLY snapshot schedule property through API. For which i am using, 
`client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage'].enableSnapshots(scheduleType, retentionCount, minute, hour, dayOfWeek, id=storageId)`

By using above API, my retention property changed successfully But others property has not changed. 
Can someone please help me on this, why other properties like; `minute`, `hour` & `dayOfWeek` are not changing

Or, Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The method is working fine for me.

Here are the script I’ve used for enabling snapshots:

```
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

storageId = 5805095
scheduleType = 'WEEKLY'
retentionCount = 4
minute = 3
hour = 3
dayOfWeek = 3

try:
    result = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage'].enableSnapshots(scheduleType, retentionCount, minute, hour, dayOfWeek, id=storageId)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    pp('Unable to enable snapshots faultCode=%s, faultString=%s' 
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Here are the script I’ve used for retrieving the updated network storage:

```
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

storageId = 5805095
objectMask = 'mask[weeklySchedule[retentionCount,minute,hour,dayOfWeek]]'

try:
    result = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage'].getObject(id=storageId, mask=objectMask)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    pp('Unable to get Network Storage=%s, faultString=%s' 
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

You could also try to edit the schedule using Control portal and see if it's possible, if don't, I suggest you to submit a ticket with another subject different from DEV-API or API